# Wireless ADC Logger Test System

Tags: datalogger

I am looking for a wireless ADC data logger system. The idea is to be able to connect to a test sensor and save output data on a pc. Ideally the system would have:

- Range of at least 10 meters
- Be battery powered
- 12 bits resolution minimum
- 2 Channel minimum, 8 preferred.
- 2kHz sample rate min
- Handle 0-5V inputs
- Save in some common format (text file, csv etc.)
- Connect to a PC either with some wireless protocol

The closest I have found is something like this:
https://store.ncd.io/product/iot-long-range-wireless-analog-digital-converter/

Comment: Purchase recommendation questions are outside the mission of this site.  If you were going to design something, you'd first have to figure out if you are looking to purely stream, purely record data that will be fetched later, or something in between with limited buffering or streaming and recording in parallel.  Starting points might be something like an Adalogger, and ESP8266 board, a bluetooth serial setup, etc.  You'd also have to consider data rate, reliability, and total runtime/data quantity.  Batteries are challenging.

Comment: Outdoors? battery capacity? charge life? data rate?

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for your help. Should I take the question down since it doesn't meet guidelines?

Comment: How many ADC channels? And in what way is the NCD link lacking?

Comment: Since this is sort of outside the scope of the site, if you provide another way to contact you, someone (I) might have ideas.

Comment: Some Arduino boards do 12 bit ADC and I think you can get your sample rate (but check). So maybe try the Arduino forum